# How to pass all cookies when making http request call?

Tags: c#, cookies, httprequest

I'm making a http request call to a service enpoint inside of a secured environment, so certain cookies have to be present or the request will fail.

When the user logs into the system, they have all the necessary cookies set.

How can I grab all the cookies and pass them along in my http request?

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        request.Method = "GET";

        request.Timeout = 1000 * 30;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000 * 60;

        using (WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream == null)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return responseData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you are building a reverse proxy.  Code Project has a good post on how to accomplish this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18490/Reverse-Proxy-in-C-NET-v2-0 which included copying cookies from one request to the other.

Be aware you will only receive cookies for the domain you app is hosted on.  If you are proxying requests to a different domain the browser sending the request will not send you cookies for the domain you are targeting.

For example if your app is at http://dev.local/ and you are forwarding the request to https://stackoverflow.com/ you will not have any cookies for the domain stackoverflow.com in your request.